# Mongodump is not exporting everything

Tags: mongodb

On production uing **mongo 4.0.6**

```js
db.issues.count();
**7984**
```

Running this daily:
`mongodump --db xx -u clientUser -p xx --out /home/xx/backup/xx$today`

On development using **mongo 4.0.3**

Importing backup with
`mongorestore --port 27017 --db xx /../backend/db/xx`

```js
db.issues.count();
**5816**
```

More than 2000 docs is missing between production and development environment. It's not the only collection missing documents.

What might be the cause of this? Unclean shutdown? Corrupt data? How do I fix it?

**Update**

Turns out, it was nothing wrong. The data was lost somehow between transfer from production to dev environment.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with what is described here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/#inaccurate-counts-without-query-predicate

Do you get different results when you run `db.issues.countDocuments({})`?

Comment: Same. I can also clearly see data is missing in my app.

Comment: This question does not have enough information for us.  For me I would do a direct comparison of the data instead of just counting them.

Comment: Is your cluster sharded?

Comment: It just resolved 2000 issues for you =) Jokes apart, it's quite tricky to reproduce. May I suggest to compare _ids between 2 databases? like in excel or simple text sort-diff? I wonder if you can spot a pattern for missing documents, which may give a clue.

Comment: What is the output of `db.issues.find().itcount();` on the production system? What is the `$today` component that is present in the `mongodump` command but not the `mongorestore` one?

Answer (score -1):

Replace the values according to your need

Prerequisites

```bash
sudo apt install mongo-tools
```

To export and import

```bash
mongoexport --host="mongodb1.example.net" --port=27017 --db="xx" --collection="xx" --out="xx.json" --username="xx" --password="xx"

mongoimport --host="mongodb1.example.net" --port=27017 --db="xx" --collection="xx" --file="xx.json"
```

Do check the documentation [mongoexport](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoexport/) & [mongoimport](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongoimport/)

Post this check if there is a difference in count.

Comment: How is this answer different than what OP said they were doing in the question? What does it change to solve their problem?

Comment: mongodump generates binary copies of data; it creates better, more efficient backups.

mongoexport can create JSON files; these can be used by other programs, and are basically human-readable as is.